# Appending to a list from an iterated dictionary

Tags: python, list

I've written a piece of script that at the moment I'm sure can be condensed. What I'm try to achieve is an automatic version of this:

```
file1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title='Select the first data file')
file2 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title='Select the first data file')
TurnDatabase = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title='Select the turn database file')

headers = pd.read_csv(file1, nrows=1).columns
data1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
data2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
```

This is how the data is collected.
There's many more lines of code which focus on picking out bits of the data. I'm not going to post it all.

This is what I'm trying to condense:

```
EntrySummary = []
for key in Entries1.viewkeys():
    MeanFRH = Entries1[key].hRideF.mean()
    MeanFRHC = Entries1[key].hRideFCalc.mean()
    MeanRRH = Entries1[key].hRideR.mean()
# There's 30 more lines of these...
# Then the list is updated  with this:
EntrySummary.append({'Turn Number': key, 'Avg FRH': MeanFRH, 'Avg FRHC': MeanFRHC, 'Avg RRH': MeanRRH,... # and so on})


EntrySummary = pd.DataFrame(EntrySummary)
EntrySummary.index = EntrySummary['Turn Number']
del EntrySummary['Turn Number']
```

This is the old code. What I've tried to do is this:

```
EntrySummary = []

for i in headers():
    EntrySummary.append({'Turn Number': key, str('Avg '[i]): str('Mean'[i])})
    print EntrySummary
# The print is only there for me to see if it's worked.
```

However I'm getting this error at the minute:

```
for i in headers():
TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable
```

Any ideas as to where I've made a mistake? I've probably made a few...

Thank you in advance

Oli

Comment: Where is `headers` defined now?

Comment: Headers is the same as the first paragraph of data that hasn't changed. Apologies I didn't make that clear

Comment: What does `print headers` give you?

Comment: `Index([u'tLap', u'sLap', u'NLap', u'vCar', u'hRideF',` and so on for about 30 more times

Comment: I think you may need `for i in headers:`

Comment: so just take away the parenthesis from the one I've already got?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look like a function, it looks like data.

Comment: If I do that I get this error: `EntrySummary.append({'Turn Number': key, str('Avg '[i]): str('Mean'[i])})
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: `'Avg '[i]`? maybe you mean `'Avg ' + i`, etc.

Comment: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: Sorry, I updated my comment: `'Avg ' + i`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your situation correctly, you want to replace the long series of assignments in the "old code" you've shown with another loop that processes all of the different items automatically using the list of headers from your data files.

I think this is what you want:

```
EntrySummary = []
for key, value in Entries1.viewitems():
    entry = {"Turn Number": key}
    for header in headers:
        entry["Avg {}".format(header)] = getattr(value, header).mean()
    EntrySummary.append(entry)
```

You might be able to come up with some better variables names, since you know what the keys and values in `Entries1` are (I do not, so I used generic names).

Comment: Thank-you I shall try and integrate this in now and get back to you!

Comment: It's doing more than what I had, although it's getting caught up. One of the columns in the data has either a yes/no value and this is the error: `raise TypeError('Could not convert %s to numeric' % str(x))
TypeError: Could not convert YESYESYESYESYESYESYESYESYES` there's a lot more yes's but I'll stop at this many

Comment: It sounds like you may need to filter the `headers` list to omit some of the columns of data that you can't take an average of.

Comment: There's 6 columns that will need omitting I'll try a quick if loop